# How can I give space in between date and todo text in the list in svelte?

Tags: javascript, mobile, visual-studio-code, electron, svelte

I've changed something like this now: https://svelte.dev/repl/f137b909d3e740f99a030576189091db?version=3.22.3

This is in Svelte, and new to it. I'm building this in electron.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: By adding space in `'My first to-do'+'Start Date'+ now` would be my first guess. Or by wrapping each text in a <span> and setting a margin.

Comment: Change `'My first to-do'+'Start Date'+ now` to `'My first to-do '+' Start Date '+ now`

Comment: Or even `'My first to-do Start Date '+ now` - the + is not needed yet

Comment: It is still sticking

Comment: Made some changes. Do you have any examples of how can change this with css?:

        <div class="todo-item-label" class:completed={completed}>{title}</div>
        <div class="todo-item-label" class:completed={completed}>{date}</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted your styles and made `todo-item-left` into a grid. Pure CSS, no other changes needed:

```
.remove-item {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .todo-item-left {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 3fr;
        justify-items: start;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

I updated the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/23dccad7e0de4d27a93d4800781b9ffd?version=3.22.3) for you to play around.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Gh05d

I just changed a few things in my code... in this one I want the button 'ENTER' to function as same as the input field above but don't know why is it not working:

THIS BUTTON CODE:

```
     <div class="buttonDate">
        <button on:click={newTodoTitle}>Enter</button>
    </div>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/f137b909d3e740f99a030576189091db?version=3.22.3

Comment: I just checked the REPL and couldn't find the code you posted. Did you change it to this: ```        <button class="enterButton" on:click="{addTodo}">Enter</button>```? By the way, it would have been better to add a comment under my post instead of making a new reply, because I only get notified when you do the former instead of the latter. Hence my late reply ;-)